# Regex credit card number format

Tags: html, regex

hi guys i just want to know the right regex for the credit card format.i have this code ^6[0-9]{15}$ but it can only accept this kind of format (6000000000000000). but i want a format like this 0000 0000 0000 0000 or 0000-0000-0000-0000.

Comment: use jquery payment js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stripe/jquery.payment/master/lib/jquery.payment.min.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Also, you didn't specify which language you want the regex in, so I'm using .NET regex syntax here.

One regex is as follows:

```
^[0-9]{4}([ -]?[0-9]{4}){3}$
```

So, this requires 4 numbers followed by 3 groups of 4 numbers with an optional separator between them. The problem is that it'll allow them to mix separators, so stuff like this is technically permissible:

```
0000-11112222 3333
```

Here's a much uglier version that eliminates this issue:

```
^[0-9]{4}(([ ][0-9]{4}){3}|(-[0-9]{4}){3}|([0-9]{4}){3})$
```

It'll force them to be consistent about which separator they're using.